# return multiple rows from node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures

**Stored Proc in MySQL**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_users`(IN `IN_Token` VARCHAR(50))
    NO SQL
BEGIN
    Select user_id, name, email 
    FROM tbluser 
    where is_active = 1 and api_token != IN_Token;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Code for sending request to stored Proc**

```
let sql = "SET @IN_Token='" + data.token + "';";
sql += "CALL sp_user_chat_users(@IN_Token);";

this.connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

**Below is the result in console?**

[image]

**Question**

As there are 3 objects coming in result. Is it good practice to write hard code like below to return the RowDataResult array?

```
results[1];
```

> 1. There are 2 Ok Packets
> 2. There is one RowDataPacket

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I gonna use Array, For example

in mysql,

```
test = function(callback) {
#connecting db;
var sql = ~~~;
this.connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
    if(error) {
       throws err;
    }
     result(null, results);
});
}
```

then, in js code

```
app.get('something', function(req, res) {
    test( function(err, data) {
        console.log(data[0].fieldCount);
        console.log(data[1].fieldCount);
    });
});
```

like this.